# Blogger's embedded CSS and JavaScript

Tags: blogger, javascript, css

I'm trying to host a blog on Blogger with a custom domain.

It's all good except the annoyance of many workplaces blocking the Blogger website using web-filters, including mine.

This is causing the blog not to render/function properly.

I can see in the Google Chrome developer tools that even though it's on my custom domain, it ask for a lot of resources from blogger.com, e.g.,

> https ://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/1535467126-widget_css_2_bundle.css
>
> https ://www.blogger.com/dyn-css/authorization.css?targetBlogID=12418145&zx=54164c77-4da2-4fc7-b3b6-5cf274c9c3b9
>
> https ://www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/2885176887-widgets.js

I'd like to replace these with custom links. Having said that, I don't see any reference to these in my template file.

Comment: Question should be migrated back to webapps:  it's about how to control where Blogger looks for certain things, not about the HTML itself.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you cannot control things that you cannot see in either your template or the Blogger interface.

The process of rendering your blogger-posts into webpages involves Blogger combining your posts, your template, and components from their "engine" (wrong word - but I'm not sure what the right one is).  There are some aspects that you have no control over.   Widgets are a particular one.

You can work around the issue for photos, through:   Photos are stored with a blogspot URL if uploaded via blogger's post editor.   But they get a googleusercontent one instead if you upload them first via Google+ Photos (or similar) and then just use the URL to load tehm to your post.

Answer (score 1):

I searched a lot, and came up with these steps to get rid of the extra CSS and Javascript offered by Blogger, which is hidden from the **"Edit HTML"** section.

Before implementing these, please make sure to save a backup of XHTML code for your blog.

1. Add `b:css='false' b:js='false'` just after `<html`.
2. First empty **CDATA** to make it look like `<b:skin><![CDATA[]]></b:skin>` and then replace it with `&lt;style&gt;&lt;!-- /*<b:skin><![CDATA[*/]]></b:skin>`.
3. Replace `</head>` with `&lt;/head&gt;&lt;!--<head/>--&gt;`.
4. Replace `</body>` with `&lt;!--</body>--&gt;&lt;/body&gt;`.

This shall get rid of all Blogger CSS and Javascript except the **Cookies Javascript**. I was not able to find anything to curb that **"Accept cookie"** prompts by Google. I think it can be forgiven, since Google is so nice to provide us such a good blogging platform for no cost.

Please add comment and let me know if any of these steps is not working as intented.